# Upload files in Google Form - unexpected error

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms

I copied this template from a link and edited it. However, everything works perfectly until I click submit and this message appears : Error encountered - unexpected error occurred.

I checked the execution transcript and here is the problem:

```
 var targetRange = sheet.getRange(lastRow+1, 1, 1, 1).setValues([[Name,Nationality,EmailAddress,DonationAmount]]);
```

I'm new at scripting so can anyone check my script? Thanks very much. 
Also I want to add 2 more file uploads to my script if possible but it didn't work.

```
// Script-as-app template.
var submissionSSKey = '1nqvlVHIi_HQOBRIoyIhoo4u0ok-g4mzssrHeEIIz99g';

function doGet(e) {
var app = UiApp.createApplication().setTitle('HowIMetMyself Registration');
var panel = app.createFormPanel();
var grid = app.createGrid(8,2).setId('registrationGrid');
var nameLabel = app.createLabel('Name');
var nameTextbox = app.createTextBox().setWidth('150px').setName('name');
var nationalityLabel = app.createLabel("Nationality");
var nationalityTextbox = app.createTextBox().setWidth('150px').setName('nationality');
var emailaddressLabel = app.createLabel('Email Address');
var emailaddressTextbox = app.createTextBox().setWidth('150px').setName('email address');
var donationamountLabel = app.createLabel('Donation Amount');
var donationamountTextbox = app.createTextBox().setWidth('150px').setName('donation amount');
var submitButton = app.createSubmitButton('<B>Submit</B>'); 
var warning = app.createHTML('<B>PLEASE WAIT WHILE DATA IS UPLOADING<B>').setStyleAttribute('background','yellow').setVisible(false)
//file upload
var upLoadTypeLabel = app.createLabel('File Upload');
var upLoad = (app.createFileUpload().setName('thefile'));
//file upload
var upLoadTypeLabel = app.createLabel('File Upload');
var upLoad = (app.createFileUpload().setName('thefile'));
//file upload
var upLoadTypeLabel = app.createLabel('File Upload');
var upLoad = (app.createFileUpload().setName('thefile'));

//Grid layout of items on form
grid.setWidget(0, 0, nameLabel)
    .setWidget(0, 1, nameTextbox)
    .setWidget(1, 0, nationalityLabel)
    .setWidget(1, 1, nationalityTextbox)
    .setWidget(2, 0, emailaddressLabel)
    .setWidget(2, 1, emailaddressTextbox)
    .setWidget(3, 0, donationamountLabel)
    .setWidget(3, 1, donationamountTextbox)
    .setWidget(4, 0, upLoadTypeLabel)
    .setWidget(4, 1, upLoad)
    .setWidget(5, 0, upLoadTypeLabel)
    .setWidget(5, 1, upLoad)
    .setWidget(6, 0, upLoadTypeLabel)
    .setWidget(6, 1, upLoad)
    .setWidget(7, 0, submitButton)
    .setWidget(7, 1, warning)


var cliHandler = app.createClientHandler().forTargets(warning).setVisible(true)
submitButton.addClickHandler(cliHandler);  
panel.add(grid);
app.add(panel);
return app;}

 function doPost(e) {
var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();  
var Name = e.parameter.Name;
var Nationality = e.parameter.Nationality;
var EmailAddress = e.parameter.emailaddress;
var DonationAmount = e.parameter.donationamount;
  //app.getElementById('info').setVisible(true).setStyleAttribute('color','red');

var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(submissionSSKey).getActiveSheet();
var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
var targetRange = sheet.getRange(lastRow+1, 1, 1, 4).setValues([[Name,Nationality,EmailAddress,DonationAmount]]);
 // data returned is a blob for FileUpload widget
 var fileBlob = e.parameter.thefile;
 var doc = DocsList.createFile(fileBlob);
 return app}
```

Comment: you get the message of var targetRange = sheet.. in execution transcript but there is no such statement in above code.

Comment: I'll post the full code then :) Thanks

Comment: @SachinK can you help me to look at it now? Thanks :)

Comment: change last line DocsList.createFile(fileBlob) to DriveApp.createFile(fileBlob);

Comment: It worked for the submission, but the data received in my google spreadsheet appears as 'undefined'. Is there any other thing wrong?

Comment: Also I wanted to have 3 file uploads but only one is working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. you need to update your **DocList** Api to **DriveApp** api
2. app.createTextBox().setWidth('150px').setname({value}) parameter in doGet(e) must matched with e.parameter.{value} in doPost(e)

like this

**in doGet(e)**

```
    var nameTextbox = app.createTextBox().setWidth('150px').setName('Name');
    var nationalityTextbox = app.createTextBox().setWidth('150px').setName('Nationality');
    var emailaddressTextbox = app.createTextBox().setWidth('150px').setName('emailaddress');
    var donationamountTextbox = app.createTextBox().setWidth('150px').setName('donationamount');
```

**in doPost(e)**

```
var Name = e.parameter.Name;
var Nationality = e.parameter.Nationality;
var EmailAddress = e.parameter.emailaddress;
var DonationAmount = e.parameter.donationamount;
```

and for the last to creating 3 file uploading you need to use unique value to each upload method  ex: setName('thefile1'),setName('thefile2'),setName('thefile3')

**Here is modified script**

```
// Script-as-app template.
var submissionSSKey = '<------Spreadsheet Key ------->';

function doGet(e) {
var app = UiApp.createApplication().setTitle('HowIMetMyself Registration');
var panel = app.createFormPanel();
var grid = app.createGrid(8,2).setId('registrationGrid');
var nameLabel = app.createLabel('Name');
var nameTextbox = app.createTextBox().setWidth('150px').setName('Name');
var nationalityLabel = app.createLabel("Nationality");
var nationalityTextbox = app.createTextBox().setWidth('150px').setName('Nationality');
var emailaddressLabel = app.createLabel('Email Address');
var emailaddressTextbox = app.createTextBox().setWidth('150px').setName('emailaddress');
var donationamountLabel = app.createLabel('Donation Amount');
var donationamountTextbox = app.createTextBox().setWidth('150px').setName('donationamount');
var submitButton = app.createSubmitButton('<B>Submit</B>'); 
var warning = app.createHTML('<B>PLEASE WAIT WHILE DATA IS UPLOADING<B>').setStyleAttribute('background','yellow').setVisible(false)
//file upload
var upLoadTypeLabel = app.createLabel('File Upload');
var upLoad1 = (app.createFileUpload().setName('thefile1'));
//file upload
var upLoadTypeLabel = app.createLabel('File Upload');
var upLoad2 = (app.createFileUpload().setName('thefile2'));
//file upload
var upLoadTypeLabel = app.createLabel('File Upload');
var upLoad3 = (app.createFileUpload().setName('thefile3'));

//Grid layout of items on form
grid.setWidget(0, 0, nameLabel)
    .setWidget(0, 1, nameTextbox)
    .setWidget(1, 0, nationalityLabel)
    .setWidget(1, 1, nationalityTextbox)
    .setWidget(2, 0, emailaddressLabel)
    .setWidget(2, 1, emailaddressTextbox)
    .setWidget(3, 0, donationamountLabel)
    .setWidget(3, 1, donationamountTextbox)
    .setWidget(4, 0, upLoadTypeLabel)
    .setWidget(4, 1, upLoad1)
    .setWidget(5, 0, upLoadTypeLabel)
    .setWidget(5, 1, upLoad2)
    .setWidget(6, 0, upLoadTypeLabel)
    .setWidget(6, 1, upLoad3)
    .setWidget(7, 0, submitButton)
    .setWidget(7, 1, warning)


var cliHandler = app.createClientHandler().forTargets(warning).setVisible(true)
submitButton.addClickHandler(cliHandler);  
panel.add(grid);
app.add(panel);
return app;}

 function doPost(e) {
var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();  
var Name = e.parameter.Name;
var Nationality = e.parameter.Nationality;
var EmailAddress = e.parameter.emailaddress;
var DonationAmount = e.parameter.donationamount;
  //app.getElementById('info').setVisible(true).setStyleAttribute('color','red');

var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(submissionSSKey).getActiveSheet();
var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
var targetRange = sheet.getRange(lastRow+1, 1, 1, 4).setValues([[Name,Nationality,EmailAddress,DonationAmount]]);
 // data returned is a blob for FileUpload widget
 var fileBlob1 = e.parameter.thefile1;
 var fileBlob2 = e.parameter.thefile2;
 var fileBlob3 = e.parameter.thefile3;
 var doc1 = DriveApp.createFile(fileBlob1);
 var doc2 = DriveApp.createFile(fileBlob2);
 var doc3 = DriveApp.createFile(fileBlob3);
 return app
 }
```

Comment: Thanks!!! I tried it but this message still appeared:  Error encountered - unexpected error occurred.

Comment: Oh it;s ok already, I forgot to add in the submission key :) Really thanks for your help!!!

Comment: Isit possible for anyone to upload files to my drive? I asked my friend to try but it doesn't work for him